# If all rows data is null hide column

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, telerik, radgrid

Using MS Visual Studio 2012, Telerik, C#.ASP.NET.

The logic I need is as follows:

```
If a columns data on all rows is null then hide the column
```

Basically if a column has 3 rows of data, if there all null then dont bother displaying that column, however if there is a value in 1 of them, then show the column.

been playing around:

```
foreach (GridColumn columns in dgvUserResults.Columns)
{
    if (columns != null)
    {
        columns.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        columns.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

code doesn't work of course doesnt iterate through the foreach loop just skips it.  Although not bothered about that even if it did iterate through I need a way to check if all column[name] rows are null. There a nice Telerik one liner?

Comment: You're just going through all the columns and of course they're not null (the column itself is there). For each column you need to go through each row and check if all the values of all the cells for that column in all rows are null.

Comment: idd thats correct like i sed that code wudnt work, not sure how to iterate through the rows and hide when all are null any example code?

Comment: "doesnt iterate through the foreach loop just skips it". It would only do that if `dgvUserResults.Columns` has no items. Are you sure `dgvUserResults` is initialized correctly at that point?

Comment: the dgv datasource is filled before this point, i think the dgv is also rebinded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try with below code snippet.

Using UniqueName

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridColumn column in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns)
    {
        // If you used ClientSelectColumn then below code is not worked For that you have to put condition
        //if(column.ColumnType  == "GridBoundColumn")

        int TotalNullRecords = (from item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items.Cast<GridDataItem>()
                                where string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item[column.UniqueName].Text) ||
                                item[column.UniqueName].Text == "&nbsp;"
                                select item).ToList().Count;

        if (TotalNullRecords == RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items.Count)
        {
            RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueName(column.UniqueName).Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

By Using Index

```
protected void RadGrid1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    foreach (GridColumn column in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Columns)
    {
        // If you used ClientSelectColumn then below code is not worked For that you have to put condition
        //if(column.ColumnType  == "GridBoundColumn")

        int TotalNullRecords = (from item in RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items.Cast<GridDataItem>()
                                where string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item[column.UniqueName].Text) ||
                                item[column.UniqueName].Text == "&nbsp;"
                                select item).ToList().Count;

        if (TotalNullRecords == RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Items.Count)
        {
            column.Visible = false;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: nice answer just getting a little syntax error, unknow method "where(?)" system.collections.generic.ITnumerable<telerik.web.ui.griddataitem

Comment: if possible then can you please provide full detail of error.

Comment: well i just ran the code to get the error, the only error its giving me on attempted build is : Error 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrWhiteSpace'.  would IsNullOrEmpty work?

Comment: Then please try "string.IsNullOrEmpty"
Because "string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace" is available from .net framework 4.0 onwards.

Comment: isnullorempty fixed the syntax error. but i have a bug, as i debug and step through, as it attempts to run the foreach loop it breaks out and doesnt run...any ideas as to why?

Comment: Please try with "RadGrid1.MasterTableView.AutoGeneratedColumns".

Comment: damn was stepping through the loop after your autogen fix and got a error, when it hit a column that was null in all the rows it errored in the code in the IF statement, error as follows: Telerik.Web.UI.GridException: Cannot find column with UniqueName 'ModuleNum9'

Comment: i suspect its to do with the autogen fix?

Comment: ah nevermidn i simply called column.visible from the loop...thanks for the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
  For col = 0 To myRadGridView.ColumnCount
        Dim mustKeepColumn As Boolean = False
        For Each r In myRadGridView.Rows

            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Cells(col).Value.ToString) Then
                mustKeepColumn = True
                Exit For
            End If

        Next
        If Not mustKeepColumn Then
            myRadGridView.Columns(col).IsVisible = False
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: there is now columnCount on the radgrid when i say dgvuserResults

Comment: its a telerik radgrid control

Comment: use instead foreach and place a variable counter.

Comment: also there is no radgrid.rows

Comment: which version of telerik rgv are you using ?

Comment: using there latest version, asp.net control is called a radgrid

Comment: `foreach (var column in dgv.Columns) { column.Visible = dgv.Rows.Any(row => row.Cells[column.Index].Value != null); }` (untested)

Comment: again rows does not exist, the way the grid is for asp.net im pretty sure rows doesnt exist and you make use of the grid "items" instead, only problem is i cant find any syntax that allows iteration through the "items" or "rows" in this example

Comment: i dont have time to search it but take a look here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/accessingcellsandrows/defaultvb.aspx